# how to join two tables on common attributes in mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

i have 2 tables:

```
table1

id message       user
1  testing       23
2  testing again 44
3  test..        23
5  lol           12
6  test..        6
```

and

```
table2

id user friend
1  23   44
2  23   6
3  19   12
4  23   32
5  23   76
6  23   89
```

i am trying to get the `messages` of all users that are friends with `23` including `23`

like:

```
id message       user   id user friend
1  testing       23     n  n    n
2  testing again 44     1  23   44
3  test..        23     n  n    n
6  test..        6      2  23   6
```

we can see that `12` is missing because he is not friend with `23` but only with `19`

i've got this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 AS w
INNER JOIN table1 AS f ON w.user = f.friend 
WHERE (w.user = 23)
```

but in case `23` has messages but no friends it will return null and also this will return other friends of `23` like `76 and 89` that have no messages..

:) confused?

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    table1.*, 
    table2.* 
FROM 
    table2 
        RIGHT JOIN table2 
        ON table2.friend = table1.user 
WEHRE 
    table2.user = 23
```

Comment: For the OP's benefit, you want to select the friends first, and then get their respective messages.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick, though the inner query may need to be modified a little bit.

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE user = 23 or friend = 23
) 
AS table2 ON table1.user = table2.user;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue its that you are ussing a INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT/RIGHT join

A Inner join return results that have registers on both tables that you are querying, so if a user does not have any friends it wont be on the result, same with messages.

You can find more information about the different kind of joins in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)