# MySQL / PHP - 2 different arguments for 1 table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the following SQL:

```
$queryString = "
            SELECT     
                iR.lastModified,
                d.*,
                c2.title as stakeholderTitle,
                u.username as authorUsername,
                c.title as authorContactName,  
                GROUP_CONCAT(iR.stakeholderRef) AS participants
            FROM
                informationRelationships iR,
                contacts c2
            INNER JOIN
                debriefs d ON
                d.id = iR.linkId 
            LEFT JOIN
                users u ON
                u.id = iR.author      
            LEFT JOIN
                contacts c ON
                c.ref = u.contactId
            LEFT JOIN 
                debriefs d2 ON
                d2.stakeholder = c2.ref                
            WHERE               
                ( 
                    iR.clientRef = '$clientRef' OR  
                    iR.contactRef = '$contactRef'   
                )
                AND    
                    iR.projectRef = '$projectRef' AND
                    iR.type = 'Debrief' 
            GROUP BY
                iR.linkId
            ORDER BY
                d.dateOfEngagement                    
        ";
```

notice how I require 2 different bits of data for the the contacts table.

So at one point, I need to match

```
c.ref = u.contactId
```

This will return one bit of information

but I also need a completely different grouping:

```
d2.stakeholder = c2.ref
```

Problem is that the title is the column i'm interested in for both:

```
c2.title as stakeholderTitle,
...
c.title as authorContactName
```

How do I go about doing this?

My current try is returning:

```
Error: Unknown column 'iR.linkId' in 'on clause'
```

[image]

I'm not sure I really understand what is happening here:

[how to join two tables on common attributes in mysql and php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697665/how-to-join-two-tables-on-common-attributes-in-mysql-and-php?rq=1)

**EDIT::::---ANSWERED--zerkms**

```
    $queryString = "
        SELECT     
            iR.lastModified,
            d.*,
            c2.title as stakeholderTitle,
            u.username as authorUsername,
            c.title as authorContactName,  
            GROUP_CONCAT(iR.stakeholderRef) AS participants
        FROM
            informationRelationships iR            
        INNER JOIN
            debriefs d ON
            d.id = iR.linkId  
        INNER JOIN 
            contacts c2 ON
            d.stakeholder = c2.ref  
        LEFT JOIN
            users u ON
            u.id = iR.author      
        LEFT JOIN
            contacts c ON
            c.ref = u.contactId             
        WHERE               
            ( 
                iR.clientRef = '$clientRef' OR  
                iR.contactRef = '$contactRef'   
            )
            AND    
                iR.projectRef = '$projectRef' AND
                iR.type = 'Debrief' 
        GROUP BY
            iR.linkId
        ORDER BY
            d.dateOfEngagement                    
    ";
```

By re-ordering my query I have managed to get both columns in... Thanks zerkms!

Comment: it clearly says that informationRelationships doesn't contain column named linkId. can you describe tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix implicit joins and explicit joins in a single query in mysql.

So

```
FROM informationRelationships iR,
     contacts c2
```

should be rewritten to

```
FROM informationRelationships iR
INNER JOIN contacts c2 ON ...
```

Comment: AHHH I see, so actually I just need the one join now that you have written this. Why did I not see this before! Ouch you have to be careful don't you!

Comment: @James T: "you have to be careful don't you" --- yep, but it would be better if mysql threw some meaningful error about that, not just confusing "unknown column"

Answer (score 0):

Do not use cartesian product and joins in the same query (not subquery), here, use only joins (CROSS JOIN is the same as cartesian product).

Comment: "Do not use cartesian product and joins in the same query" --- this is not clear enough. Please clarify

Comment: `FROM informationRelationships iR CROSS JOIN contacts c2 ON 1 = 1 INNER JOIN debriefs d ON d.id = iR.linkId ...` instead `FROM informationRelationships iR, contacts c2 INNER JOIN debriefs d ON d.id = iR.linkId ...`

Comment: "Do not use cartesian product and joins" --- but you propose to use cartesian product and join, don't you? ;-)

Comment: OK, I mean that there seems to be a problem combining dot separated list of relations for cartesian products and joins at a same query (probably this is because of relative algebra and priority). So using the other way for representing cartesian product (cross join) seems to overcome the problem. Now I look at your answer, it says the same :)

Comment: the thing - the issue has nothing to do with cartesian product at all. If OP didn't have a cartesian product - the issue would still be there.